# Specify members who'll receive email notifications in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

we're having a project which includes an Android app & an iOS app. The project manager, developers, content managers all have access to it. The problem is, whenever the apps crashed, everyone get an email reporting that crash, which is only needed by the app developers. So I would like to know if we can specify which member will get which type of email notification (ie Android & iOS crashing reporting will only be sent to the  corresponding dev)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some amount of configuration you can perform for Firebase Crash Reporting email alerts.  Everyone who has access to your project should review their own personal settings under User Settings (three vertical dots menu in the upper right of the console).  Click through to Alert Subscriptions, choose an app, then specify the events for which they want an email.

Comment: I want to add more members for crash alert in firebase is it possible?,actually was not able to find that